# What’s the best way to report an IP address from Romania?

Tags: ip, account-security

I recently received an email from a company sending me a security code that I didn’t ask for. It showed me the IP address that the request came from and it shows that it is in Romania but I live in the US. How can i report this adress?

Comment: There is no effective recourse other than reporting it to the company that sent you the email (and potentially changing your password)

Comment: So, some online service sent a security code to log into their service? Could it simply be that a valid customer used your email address by mistake when they signed up? Or are you a customer of this company?

Comment: Was it one of those 'You have been hacked, click here' mails? if so, better check the mail itself, because it might be a phishing mail. They show IP addresses from eastern european countries because of the weaker legislations there so you freak out and click the fake button right away.

Answer (score 2):

First, you must find the ISP that owns this IP. Whois is a good tool for that.

After that, search for the *abuse* address, usually is `abuse@ispdomain.com`. You can send a complaint there.

The problem is that they usually never reply nor do anything. If you put yourself in their place, they are receiving a complaint from a random stranger from another country accusing one of their paying customers, without solid proof. So, no reason to do anything.

And a security code is not even remotely problematic. If some client from that ISP robbed you hundreds of thousands of dollars, and you got some [TLA](http://don.fed.wiki.org/view/three-letter-agencies) on your side, maybe they will respond. And don't think you can do anything even with that: cross-country jurisdiction is complicated, to say the least.

On your case, keep your hopes low. As low as possible. Send the email, but don't wait for much.

Comment: From the description, I'm not sure there is any abuse going on

Comment: Stretching a lot, someone is using his password without permission. That could remotely be classified as abuse.

Comment: How is the password used without permission? I get these types of emails almost weekly when people use my email address by mistake. And they are all for services I am not a user.

Comment: OP does not states that, but I sometimes get the _confirm new device access_ on accounts I don't care about, used a short password 20 years ago and never bothered to close or change passwords...

Comment: My point is that there is not enough information for us to determine what the emails are about. There could be no abuse. If there is no abuse, then if the OP followed your advice, then it might just end up in confusion.

Comment: This isn't the only solution. You can submit it to various scam databases.